# pipe both, stdout and stderr in the fish shell

Tags: fish

I know this has been an issue for a while and I found a lot of discussion about it, however I didn't get which would be finally a way to get it done: pipe both, stdout and stderr. In bash, this would be simply:

```
cmd 2>&1 | cmd2
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

That syntax works in fish too. A demo:

```
$ function cmd1
      echo "this is stdout"
      echo "this is stderr" >&2
  end

$ function cmd2
      rev
  end

$ cmd1 | cmd2
this is stderr
tuodts si siht

$ cmd1 &| cmd2
rredts si siht
tuodts si siht
```

Docs: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#redirects

Comment: perfect. it turned out that I used an older version.

Comment: to redirect to a file, `echo meow > /tmp/meow 2>&1` works for me. you need the stderr redirection after the stdout redirection.

Comment: Why do you use `sh -c` in function `cmd1`, while `echo "this is stdout"; echo "this is stderr" >&2` simply works

Comment: As for why you need `2>&1` after `> /tmp/meow`, it's because redirection is “dumb”. If you do `2>&1` first, `stderr` gets sent to `stdout`, which is the terminal, and then if you redirect `stdout`, `stderr` doesn't get the message and remains pointed at the terminal.

Answer (score 16):

There's also a handy shortcut, per these [docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html?highlight=redirects#input-output-redirection)

### `&>`

Here's the relevant quote (emphasis and white space, mine):

> As a convenience, **the redirection** `&>` can be used to direct **both stdout**
> **and stderr** to the same destination. For example:
>
> ```
> echo hello &> all_output.txt
> ```
>
> redirects both *stdout* and *stderr* to the file
> `all_output.txt`. This is equivalent to `echo hello > all_output.txt 2>&1`.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Worth noting that more than just stdout and stderr but all output FDs seem to be forwarded with this.  I was struggling with a parallel app that was outputting multiple processes via &3 &4 etc.  &> gets them all which is super helpful.

Comment: After following S.O.'s little badge treats back to this post, reread @BoeroBoy's comment, and realized that the `>` in `&>` is easy to remember once you know that it "gets them all," since it looks like a funnel (or, as we learned in gradeschool, an an alligator) swallowing _all_ the outputs. 